# How to show pie chart in android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I want to build an app in where I want to show memory and cpu usage map in a pie chart . However I have no idea about how to implement this .

I have seen the following question :

[How to display the 3D pie chart asynchronously in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000492/how-to-display-the-3d-pie-chart-asynchronously-in-android)

But I could not resolve this issue . What can I do ? Guys , can u help me in this regard ?

Comment: what is your problem? creating pie chart? or finding memory cpu usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "paint" a graph on android you can use a third-party-lib.
All libs supports different types of charts.

There are some graph-libs for Android:

1. [afreechart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) is based on jfreechart.
   License: LGPL
   Version: 0.0.4
2. [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)
   License: Apache
   Version: 1.2.0
   Maven: yes. (custom repo?)
3. [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/)
   License: Apache
   Version: 0.6.0 
   Maven: yes
4. [GraphView](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview)
   License: Apache?
   Version: ?
   Maven: ?

I've found not so much about it. But it seems to be free.

1. [DroidCharts](https://code.google.com/p/droidcharts/)
   License: LGPL
   Version: r2?
   Maven: ?
2. [Chartdroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)
   License: Apache
   Version: 2.0.0
   Maven: ?

Or you implements your own :)
It's not the perferct answer, but maybe a good hint.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/) to create different kinds of charts. For example you can find lots of links like these two

[link1](http://danielkvist.net/code/piechart-with-achartengine-in-android), [link2](http://mukeshsoni.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/how-to-setup-achartengine-within-an-activity/)

[here](http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/08/31/exploring-android-charting-and-graphs-solutions/) is another nice example you can look at

Comment: The full project is not there . Only a snippet of code is provided .

Comment: sad .. why do you need the full project? just learn from the example.. and also check the full api in achartengine

Comment: Yes, thats right . But which function must be called by me to draw piechart ? I have seen Link1 .